# JsTranslationBundle fallback locale doesn't work

Tags: javascript, symfony

When using JsTranslationBundle with a configured fallback local, the ajax call that retrieves the translations doesn't return the ones for the fallback - only the current locale.

I set the fallback correctly like this:

```
bazinga_js_translation:
    locale_fallback: 'de'
```

Furthermore, why does the `trans()` function take a locale as parameter if new translations cannot be fetch?

```
Translator.trans(translationKey, [], 'messages', 'nl_NL')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the bundle is not accepting locales with region for the fallback, so changing the following worked for me:

```
bazinga_js_translation:
    locale_fallback: de_DE # with region
```